# Get selections for multiple BootstrapTable tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

i'm using wenzhixin bootstrap table, and I have a lot of tables in the same page and one button, and when the button is clicked i want to gather all the selected rows from all the different tables.

so, 
in my `JS` code i did: (`Ids` is an array with all the tables IDs)

```
for (var i = 0; i < Ids.length; i++)
{
    var domain = $.map($('#' + Ids[i] + '').bootstrapTable('getSelections'), function (row)
    {
        // do something with row object...
    });
}
```

but it's not working...
please help!

Comment: You are using the correct method `bootstrapTable('getSelections')` you should have an array of selected rows object containing their values of columns.Does `console.log(row)` inside map function give anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was my mistake, as some of the id's contain a vertical bar character `|` and it is not a valid character for id in `JavaScript`. the `$.map` function returned an error because of the id with the vertical bar.